How to convert my Django project to an exe file?
I have done a project using Django which has four Django apps. I am trying to distribute my project to someone as a standalone executable file. I am using PyInstaller for that. But, it detects only the main Django app and it can't find the other three apps. What am I doing wrong? I have successfully created an exe file. But upon running it I get an error saying that it doesn't find one of my Django apps.
This is the error I got on the window. homepage is one my four apps. core is my main app which settings.py and the other two are transactions and inventory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "django\core\management\__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "django\apps\config.py", line 178, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'homepage'


Does this answer your question? how to run Django locally as a windows executable app
